# What's going on with "expected specifier-qualifier-list" error

Tags: objective-c, debugging, iphone-sdk-3.0

It is my GameEngine.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameArray.h";


@interface GameEngine : NSObject {
    GameArray *gameButtonsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GameArray *gameButtonsArray;
```

And this is my GameArray.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyAppDelegate.h";

@interface GameArray : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *gameButtonsArray;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *gameButtonsArray;
```

It keep prompt my  "expected specifier-qualifier-list" error i my GameEngine.h, and error said that  "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'GameArray'", what's going on?

Comment: I changed my "gameButtonsArray" in GameArray.h to myGameButtonsArray, it also prompt this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best practice.

GameEngine.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class GameArray;

@interface GameEngine : NSObject {
    GameArray *gameButtonsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GameArray *gameButtonsArray;
```

Then in GameEngine.m

```
#import "GameEngine.h"
#import "GameArray.h"

@implementation GameEngine    
//...
@end
```

This prevents circular references wherein one header imports a second header which imports the first which imports the second and so on in an endless cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the semi-colon on line 2 in your `.h` file

Comment: just added , still got the problems.

Comment: I see that you have edited the question and ADDED semi-colons on line 2 of both .h files.  You need to REMOVE them.

Answer (score 0):

If removing the unnecessary semicolons does not fix your problem, most likely *MyAppDelegate.h* imports *GameEngine.h* creating a circular dependency between the *GameEngine.h* and *GameArray.h*.  Try removing the `#import "GameArray.h"` from *GameEngine.h* and replacing it with:

```
@class GameArray;
```

Also add

```
#import "GameArray.h"
```

to *GameEngine.m* below the import of *GameEngine.h*