# @class vs. import

Tags: objective-c, import

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between @class and #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361077/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-import)
>   [Objective-C @class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)

Hi

Can anyone explain the difference between @class and import in objective c? When shall I use which? Is either preferable/more efficient?

Many thanks

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import

Comment: @dcp, @mipadi Thank you both very much. That answered my question. For some reason non of these links came up when I searched for similar questions.